# What environment is still using the Token Ring network?

Tags: network, lan

I have struggled to find what kind of environment (Eg: Educational, Medical environment, etc) where the Token Ring network is still used in this present time and why are they still being used.

It is for part of my group assignment and we have searched through the entire internet and still can't find any clue as Ethernet has taken over Token Ring nowadays. It is my first time asking here if you have any suggestions regarding **which environment in the society today still using the Token Ring network and why?**

Comment: There may be a few ancient installations, but Token Ring has long since vanished into obscurity, given its comparatively low performance - it is outperformed by switched Fast Ethernet which is old already. However, questions for resources are off-topic here as is speculation.

Comment: Token Ring was developed by IBM, and IBM was dominant in banking and other large financial entities.  But as @Zac67 points out, it's terribly obsolete.  No one makes hardware for it anymore, and any serious network has long since upgraded.  There may be some system somewhere still using it.  But that's just a guess.

Comment: You're asking about historical trivia -- which is off topic. It *was* common in lots of places -- medical, banking, education, government, telecom, etc. (so was Appletalk, and IPX, btw.) Any remaining in 2020 will be in the extremest of extreme legacy systems. No one has made any token-ring gear for decades, so any gear you ever see will likely be older than you are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some older industrial network protocols do use this. For example Modbus + or for multiple masters in a Profibus ring can use this, in combination with a master-slave network:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profibus

However, as an example even Profinet Class A over fast ethernet links is significantly faster and cheaper.